# Как отобразить элементы html в UILabel?

Tags: cocoa, objective-c

Добрый день, пишу приложение, оно получает с сервера текст с тегами `<b>text</b>` и `<a href="">link</a>` нужно корректно отобразить эти куски текста в UILable или в UITextView на крайний случай. Хотелось бы получить простое решение без использования сторонних хтмл парсеров с километрами кода.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сторонние фреимворки не нужны, html умеет показывать встроенный UIWebView, для отбражения строки воспользуйтесь его методом

```
- (void)loadHTMLString:(NSString *)string baseURL:(NSURL *)baseURL
```

По поводу отсутствия в строке всяких <HTML> и <Body> я честно говоря не помню как он себя ведет, но если что, можно их и динамически подставить. Если внешний вид настроить и вырубить userInterectionEnabled от лейбла и не отличишь.

Что же касается собственно UILabel, до 6.0 он вообще умел выводить текcт только с единым форматированием т.е. цвет, шрифт, размер и т.п. можно было задать только для компонента в целом, в 6.0 появилось свойство attributedText, но я не знаю как оно работает - для всех программ в разработке которых я учавствовал требуется поддержка начиная с 4.3, так что мне не приходилось с ним сталкиваться, а почитать мануал вы и без меня можете :)

Comment: Я уже думал в сторону WebView единственное, интересно сколько будет оно памяти кушать, тк у меня таблица и в каждом cell необходимо отображать разный текст, с iOS6.0+ проблем впринцепи нет)

Comment: WebView не вариант, попробовал, тормозит при скролинге активном. при том, что у меня выгружаются вьюхи которых не видно на экране